# How to print very big numbers to the screen

Tags: java

In an interview I had, I was asked to write a program that prints to the screen the numbers 1,2,3,4,5....until 99999999999999.....?(the last number to print is the digit 9 million times)
You are not allowed to use Big-Integer or any other similar object.
The hint I got is to use modulo and work with strings, I tried to think about it but haven't figured it out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying it should eventually print a number consisting of 9 million digits? If so, create a `byte[9_000_000]`, set the last byte to `'1'`, then print using `write(buf, 8_999_999, 1)`. Increment to `'2'`, print, increment, print, ... when `'9'` set previous byte to `1`, and last byte to `0`, then print them, and continue until the end of the universe (how long it's gonna take to count that far).

Comment: @Andreas what if it's to be stored in a file, storage or display is not the question here. Intention seems to be to create an algorithm to generate next number. I can't think of a method which uses modular operations to get to the next big number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an array to store the number, and perform operations on the array.

Here's an example

```
public class BigNumberTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*Array with the digits of the number. 0th index stores the most significant digit*/
        //int[] num = new int[1000000];

        //Can have a million digits, length is 1 + needed to avoid overflow
        int[] num = {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

        int base = 10;
        int step = 1;
        String endNum = "100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020";//Can have a million digits

        while(true) {
            //Increment by step
            for(int carry = step, i = num.length - 1; carry != 0 && i >= 0; i--) {
                int newDigit = num[i] + carry;

                num[i] = newDigit % base;
                carry = newDigit / base;
            }

            //Find the position of most significant digit
            int mostSignificantDigitIndex = 0;
            while(num[mostSignificantDigitIndex] ==  0) {/*No need to check if firstNonZero < num.length, as start num >=0 */
                mostSignificantDigitIndex++;
            }

            StringBuilder strNum = new StringBuilder();
            //Concatenate to get actual string
            for(int i = mostSignificantDigitIndex; i < num.length; i++) {
                strNum.append(num[i]);
            }

            System.out.println(strNum);

            //Check if number current number is greater or equal to endNum
            if(strNum.length() > endNum.length() || (strNum.length() == endNum.length() && strNum.toString().compareTo(endNum) >= 0)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
```

Comment: Doing `string += string` in a loop is exceedingly slow, and this will generate a lot of garbage, if code has to count `10^9000000` times. And then to use regex on top of that. If I had been the interviewer, I'd consider this a fail.

Comment: I thought of that, I was being lazy.

Comment: When interviewing, signs of laziness is also a fail.

Comment: I read it again and there were a quite a few problems other than the efficiency, fixed those along with the string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

This is a PHP, but you could transform it to java easy...
Recursion with increasing number through string.

```
function nextNum($num="", $step=1, $end="999999999999999999") {
    $string = "";
    $saving = 0;
     for($i=strlen($num)-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
        $calc = intval(intval($num[$i]) + $saving);
        if ($i==(strlen($num)-1)) $calc = $calc + $step;

        if (strlen($calc)==2) {
            $calc = $calc."";
            $saving = intval($calc[0]);
            $calc = intval($calc[1]);
            }
        else {
            $calc = intval($calc);
            $saving = 0;
            }

        $string = $calc . $string;
        }

    if ($saving!=0) $string = $saving.$string;

    echo $string." ";
    if ($end == $string || strlen($end)<strlen($string)) { return; }
    else return nextNum($string, $step, $end);
}
nextNum("0", 1, "999999999999999999");
```

I didn't test it... but it should work..

Comment: What will PHP use to store a number with 9 million digits?